# Tentando um CRUD com Asp.Net Core 3.1 e dá erro na conexão com o Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

Essa é minha string de conexão

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "bdcoreconn": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BdCoreCrud;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=sa;Password=Simb@d123;"
  },
```

No Startup.cs tenho isso:

```
 services.AddDbContext<CrudContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("bdcoreconn")));
```

Esse é meu Contexto:

```
public class CrudContext: DbContext
    {
        public CrudContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Desenvolvedor> Desenvolvedores { get;set; }
        public DbSet<Projeto> Projetos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LancamentoHoras> Lancamentos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProjetoDesenvolvedor> ProjetoDesenvolvedores { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Desenvolvedor>()
                .HasKey(p => p.IdDesenvolvedor);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LancamentoHoras>()
                .HasKey(p => p.IdLancamentoHoras);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Projeto>()
                .HasKey(p => p.IdProjeto);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProjetoDesenvolvedor>()
                .HasKey(p => p.IdProjetoDesenvolvedor);
        }
    }
```

Quando eu dou um `SaveChanges()`, pego esse erro:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
> Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Eu alterei no startup a forma de obter a string de conexão para essa aqui

```
var connection = @"Server=DESKTOP-K4MI90D\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BdCoreCrud;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=sa;Password=Simb@d123;";
            services.AddDbContext<CrudContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Observe que no swagger o erro mudou. Aparece um tal de

> Erro 500
> Undocumented

E não sei o que é isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: *"Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?"* é preciso por uma string válida e confirmar que o banco de dados está respondendo com essa configuração. Já tentou conectar com essas settings no Management Studio?

Comment: @RicardoPontual, é dessa forma que me conecto. Essa última configuração foi tentativa. Mas a conexão pelo Management é dessa forma: `DESKTOP-K4MI90D\SQLEXPRESS` e demais usuário e senha. E mesmo assim pego o mesmo erro. Só não reiniciei a máquina ainda.

Comment: essas barras duplas podem ser um problema, já tentou com `.\SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: Não aceita barra simples. Dá erro de cara. Tentei localhost e a mesma coisa.

Comment: O erro base é: `Could not open connection to sql server`. Será que falta algum outro passo para eu fazer?

Comment: @pnet Você já garantiu que tem acesso à base usada na connection string, certo?

Comment: @LINQ, sim. Eu uso, pois as tabelas nesse banco eu criei pelo management. Acho que falta um mapeamento ou sei lá.

Comment: Fiz uma edição com nova forma de obter a string de conexão e a mensagem do erro mudou.

Comment: Ao que tudo indica sua string de conexão ainda está errada ou você tem algum problema de configuração do SQLExpress em sua máquina

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, o que estava errado era o Contexto. Faltou definir o método: `protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)` feito isso funcionou. Agradeço a todos aí.

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente você deve ser sua conexão:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-N8415MR\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BdCoreCrud;User Id=sa;Password=Simb@d123;"
  },


 services.AddDbContext<CrudContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

O seu OnModelCreating e onde fica os mapeamentos,
o ideal seria você fazer desta forma, faz a criação de uma
pasta apenas para o mapeamento das classes

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UsuarioMapping());//ok

            //evitar a deleção em cascade
            foreach (var foreignKey in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
            {
                foreignKey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
            }

        }
```

Exemplo de mapeamento:

```
 public class UsuarioMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Usuario>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Usuario> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            builder.Property(p => p.NomeCompleto).IsRequired().HasColumnType("varchar(100)");
            builder.Property(p => p.Imagem).HasColumnType("varchar(100)");
            builder.Property(e => e.CentroDeCusto).HasMaxLength(50).IsUnicode(false);
            builder.Property(e => e.CodigoUsuario).HasMaxLength(10).IsUnicode(false).IsFixedLength();


            builder.Property(e => e.Ativo).HasMaxLength(1).IsUnicode(false);
            builder.Property(e => e.DataCadastro).HasColumnType("datetime");
            builder.Property(e => e.DataAlteracao).HasColumnType("datetime");


            builder.HasOne(d => d.Empresa)
                .WithMany(p => p.Usuario)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdEmpresa);

            builder.HasOne(d => d.Funcao)
                .WithMany(p => p.Usuario)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdFuncao);

            builder.HasOne(d => d.Departamento)
                .WithMany(p => p.Usuario)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdDepartamento);


            builder.ToTable("Usuario");
        }

    }
```